# PHP/mysql, Using foreign keys to get data from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one called `posts` and one called `users`. Inside `posts` I have several columns, one being a foreign key of `userid`. In my `users` table I have several columns including a `userid` and a `username`. I want to use the `posts.userid` to find the `users.userid` and show `users.username`. Currently I am using:

```
SELECT posts.postid, posts.title, posts.text, posts.link, posts.good, posts.bad, posts.userid
FROM posts
```

To get the data about each post and,

```
SELECT users.username, users.userid, posts.userid
FROM users, posts
WHERE users.userid = posts.userid
```

to get the data about each user, but when I do this the output of `echo $row_therealuserid['username'];` is always just the first user.

Comment: Where'd `$row_therealuserid` come from?

Comment: Please explain your php code executing the SQL

Comment: @PaulP.R.O.  I'm using dreamweaver to add bindings and that is what it used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use an [array to fetch the other rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), then loop through that array.

```
$query = 'SELECT users.username, users.userid, posts.userid
FROM users, posts
WHERE users.userid = posts.userid';

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['username'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it'll work. I had to leave for Chemistry class right after posing this question, I should be back at my computer to test it in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

For SELECT and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a **resource** on success, or FALSE on error.

A **resource** is a special variable, holding a reference to an external resource. Resources are created and used by special functions, and it can has many types created and used by different functions.

for    mysql_query() the returned type a resource is "*mysql result*" which will be used by  mysql_fetch_array();

I will give you another example, for the function    mysql_connect() it returns a resource type "*mysql link*" which can be used by the function    mysql_query()